# AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute and Index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

could anybony help because i am struggling two days in order to retrive basic information on the product (product name, picture,rating , price) in the link provided here.  this my code and i am new to python

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import randint
from bs4.dammit import EncodingDetector
import re
import sys


url='https://fr.aliexpress.com/category/205000316/men-clothing-accessories.html'
headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0,Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0',Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0',Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; EN; rv:11.0) like Gecko',Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)',Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)',Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A'"

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.decode('utf8', 'ignore'), "html.parser")


# retrive infos such product name, price , rating
Prod=soup.find_all('ul', class_='util-clearfix son-list')

for item in Prod:
    print(item.contents[0].find_all("span",{"class:","star star-s "[0].text)
    print(item.contents[0].find_all("span",{"class:","star star-s "[0].text)
    print(item.contents[0].find_all("span",{"class:","star star-s "[0].text)
```

Comment: why do you get three times the same element ? Maybe use second `for` loop inside first `for`.

Comment: it seems like you a printing the same index over and over should probably use dynamic index like contents[i]

Answer (score 1):

Your first error is that the `Prod` actually matches the list of products - the `ul` element, while you need the inner `li` elements - each representing a product container.

Then, once you change it to locate products - iterate over the product containers and look for inner elements containing a name, rating and other desired information. For that, you would need browser developer tools to understand what HTML elements represent the data you need to extract:

```
products = soup.select('ul.son-list li.list-item')
for product in products:
    name = product.select_one("a.product").get_text()
    stars_element = product.select_one(".star")
    rating = stars_element["title"].split(": ")[1].strip().split(" ", 1)[0] if stars_element else "Unknown rating"

    print(name, rating)
```

Prints:

```
Lurker Requin Peau Soft Shell V4 Tactique Militaire Veste Hommes Imperméable Coupe-Vent Chaud Manteau À Capuchon de Camouflage C... 4.8
HEYGUYS coton t chemises hommes new summer street wear hanche hop T-SHIRTS 2017 marque de mode fermeture éclair sur la manche t-... 4.8
2017 Nutella Motif Hommes et Femmes Hoodies Couples Casual Style 3D Impression Personnalité Automne Hiver Sweats À Capuche Survê... 4.8
...
```

Comment: hi thanks this works perfectly but could u please explain this line rating = stars_element["title"].split(": ")[1].strip().split(" ", 1)[0] if stars_element else "Unknown rating"

Comment: @Ilyas it's just one way to get the numerical rating value out of the "title" attribute..

Comment: thanks a lot alecxe but if i want to insert this list into sqlite , how can i do , have you any idea but i have tried but any success

Answer (score 0):

Product name, image, price:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://fr.aliexpress.com/category/205000316/men-clothing-accessories.html'

headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0,Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0',Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0',Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; EN; rv:11.0) like Gecko',Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)',Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)',Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A'"

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.decode('utf8', 'ignore'), "html.parser")

products = soup.find_all('div', class_='item')

for item in products:
    print(' item:', item.find(class_='info').find("a").text)
    print('price:', item.find(class_="price").find(class_='value').text)
    print('image:', item.find(class_="pic").find("img")['src'])
    print('--')
```

Result:

```
 item: Rocksir punisher t chemises pour hommes t-shirt Coton de mode marque t shirt hommes Casual Manches Courtes le punisher T-shirt h...
price: € 12,05 - 12,92
image: //ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ByVZSpXXXXcxaXXXq6xXFXXXW/New-Design-Male-Novelty-Men-T-shirt-Fashion-Cotton-O-neck-Hip-Hop-T-shirt-.jpg_220x220.jpg
--
 item: DIFFELEMENT 2017 Nouveau style long Manteau Hommes marque vêtements mode Long Vestes Manteaux marque-vêtements hommes Pardessus ...
price: € 44,82
image: //ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB12IqMXEAKL1JjSZFkq6y8cFXa2/DIFFELEMENT-2017-New-style-long-Coat-Men-brand-clothing-fashion-Long-Jackets-Coats-brand-clothing-mens.jpg_220x220.jpg
--
```